# Как узнать является ли тип перечислением?

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-нибудь проверить, является ли тип перечислением, т.е. `enum` или `enum class`?

Comment: Странно, два пользователя созданные сегодня один задал вопрос - второй быстро ответил, быстрее всех, и получили достаточно балов быстро. Что-то тут не чисто

Comment: @nick_n_a придется принимать другой ответ, а то забанят

Comment: @nick_n_a всё нормально, пользователи разные, не забаним )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
enum E {};
enum class Ec : int {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_enum<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<E>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<Ec>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_enum<int>::value << '\n';
}
```

Ну, или

```
std::cout << std::is_enum<A>() << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_enum<E>() << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_enum<Ec>() << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_enum<int>() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с C++11 — да. Это можно сделать с помощью шаблонного класса [`std::is_enum`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) в заголовочном файле `type_traits`.